# XSLT transformation : Updating nodes of output xml

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

I have following scenario, which I am trying to work through. I am not entirely sure if my solution is correct in first place (but it works using XPath and C# code). Have replicated almost similar logic in xslt too.

**Point to note :**
XML is an input from third party. I can not change its structure.

so my input xml is something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Houses>
    <House id="0" address="House1" area="XX"/>
    <House id="1" address="House2" area="XX"/>
    <House id="0" address="House1" area="YY"/>
    <House id="1" address="House2" area="YY"/>
  </Houses>
  <VisitModule>
    <VisitedBy personID="ABC">
      <VisitedArea id="XX">
        <VisitedHouse houseID="0" isVisited="false" />
        <VisitedHouse houseID="1" isVisited="false" />
      </VisitedArea>
    </VisitedBy>
    <VisitedBy personID="XYZ">
      <VisitedArea id="XX">
        <VisitedHouse houseID="0" isVisited="true" />
        <VisitedHouse houseID="1" isVisited="false" />
      </VisitedArea>
      <VisitedArea id="YY">
        <VisitedHouse houseID="0" isVisited="false" />
        <VisitedHouse houseID="1" isVisited="false" />
      </VisitedArea>
    </VisitedBy>
  </VisitModule>
</Root>
```

What I wish to achieve is, if the house is ever visited by any person, then that house will be marked as visited else not.

The output xml I need is somewhat like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <VisitedArea id="XX">
    <!--If covered by any person, its covered=true.-->
    <House id ="0" covered="true" />
    <House id ="1" covered="false" />
  </VisitedArea>
  <VisitedArea id="YY">
    <House id ="0" covered="false" />
    <House id ="1" covered="false" />
  </VisitedArea>
</Root>
```

I already have this working as part of XML traversal. But its unbelievably slow (since the current input XML is gigantic). Hence was hoping to do it via XSLT, which should be faster.

Idea I have used is, go through each house node, find its matching houseID based on area and id, and then do the calculations.

I have gotten most of it working in XSLT except for the point where I need to update the data of existing node, say house 1 of area XX, which was previously not visited but now I find a person node who has visited this house, so I need to now set that node as

```
covered=true
```

I couldn't find anything which would point to editing the currently being transformed document. I am not saying my approach is 100% correct, so am open to other ideas too. But I think using XSLT would make my life a lot easier in terms of maintenance, than the actual code, so very much hoping to get it done in XSLT.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution using XSLT. It works by getting a distinct list of all the areas, then using the list of houses under the `Houses` child element, checks each one to see if there are any nodes matching under the visited areas where that house is covered to get the right value for the `covered` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- get distinct list of areas -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="//House/@area[not(.=following::House/@area)]">
          <xsl:call-template name="areaTemplate">
            <xsl:with-param name="areaCode" select="." />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- for each area check each house to see if covered -->
    <xsl:template name="areaTemplate">
      <xsl:param name="areaCode" />
      <VisitedArea id="{$areaCode}">
      <xsl:for-each select="//House[@area=$areaCode]">
        <xsl:variable name ="houseId" select="@id" />
        <xsl:variable name ="covered" select="boolean(//VisitedArea[@id=$areaCode]/VisitedHouse[@isVisited='true' and @houseID=$houseId])" />
        <House id="{$houseId}" covered="{$covered}" />
      </xsl:for-each>
      </VisitedArea>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output, given your sample input XML, should be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <VisitedArea id="XX">
    <House id="0" covered="true" />
    <House id="1" covered="false" />
  </VisitedArea>
  <VisitedArea id="YY">
    <House id="0" covered="false" />
    <House id="1" covered="false" />
  </VisitedArea>
</Root>
```

I haven't tested for performance of it; an alternative approach might be to deserialize your input xml into classes to manipulate them into the necessary groups and then serialize back to your target xml.

Comment: Hi Steve, I gave it a quick try, and I could implement the idea, though there was an issue with duplicate nodes but probably just my extra logic. Also, just as info, I don't think XSLT is helping much with performance aspect :(
Anyway will check my logic once and get back this weekend :) Thanks for the view.

Comment: Serialization solved all my worries. Massive performance improvements. So my running time is down to almost 10-15 mins from almost hour and half. And C# logic with it meant i could easily update values.
I wish I could double vote your answer :')